# Hadoop Job Automation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have hadoop 3 node cluster which is used to analyse the data every day at 9 PM. I want to automate the running job in hadoop command line. How can i do that.

Comment: What OS is your cluster on, Ubuntu?

Comment: i am having hadoop cluster in Ubuntu VMS

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted?

Comment: Well, did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using linux, I'll recommend you use the cron scheduler.
Look at [a this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out oozie, it's a workflow manager for hadoop and I believe it has the ability to schedule jobs